# How to create a loop that checks if "Remove" exists for multiple "Remove"

Tags: python, selenium, helium

How to loop the below logic inside a script, till all are deleted then continue to the next text.

```
if Text("Remove").exists():
click("Remove")
```

Explaination:

==============

WEBPAGE 1
CONTENTS:

—
A (REMOVE)
—
B (REMOVE)
—
C (REMOVE)

[ “Remove” is a clickable link that removes A, B ,C]

==============

Part of my script now:

if Text(“Remove”).exists():
    click(“Remove”)
    click(“OK”)

===============

Result:

WEBPAGE 1
CONTENTS:

—

—
B (REMOVE)
—
C (REMOVE)

================

Above A is removed by the script.
My question is how can i loop that, so the result is:

===============

Result:

WEBPAGE 1
CONTENTS:

—

—

—

================

So for every text on the webpage that containts “Remove”
It executes the script untill there is no “Remove” anymore.

Comment: List of strings, iterate over the list? More detail is needed to fully answer.

Comment: Hi, there are no strings corresponding. Edited the post.

Comment: What do you mean? `"Remove"` is a string. You need to provide more information on exactly what you are trying to do. As it stands, your question is unclear and may be closed.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Please provide us with an array or list or whatever you have with the contents and an explanation on what condition you want what to happen.

Comment: "Remove" is a text string (external) (on a webpage)

Comment: My question is on how to do a loop with this untill everthing on the external webpages with remove is removed then continue

Comment: So, you have code to find this text on the web-pages, yes?

Comment: <a id="Remove">Remove</a>

Comment: how to you read webpages? Iterate over them replace the string you are tyring to remove with empty string `''`. In case if it is html content, replace that. `page.replace('<a id="Remove">Remove</a>', '')`  You should provide with details for other to help.

Comment: do you want to remove the content with tag `remove`? details man

Comment: @Gorilla Please do not vandalize your posts. If you try to revandalize a post that has been fixed, a moderator will be informed. The moderator will roll back your vandalism, and hand you a suspension which will prevent you from further editing. **Attempts at vandalism are ultimately futile.**

Answer (score 0):

String have a replace method which you can directly use to replace the word with `''`

```
page = 'Lorem remove ipsum elit remove id justo eu, finibus remove'
page2 = 'Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora remove remove remove'

pageList = [page, page2]

for page in pageList:
    while 'remove' in page:
        page = page.replace('remove', '')
    print page

#Out: Lorem  ipsum elit  id justo eu, finibus 
#Out: Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora
```

If it is specific HTML content replace that.

```
page.replace('<a id="Remove">Remove</a>', '')
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Im going to look into it, response will come.

Comment: Explained a lot more above!

Comment: try changing `if` to `while`

Answer (score 0):

Since Your mind is orbiting around .remove() :

```
a = 'This is just a Test'
a_list = []

for i in range(0, len(a) - 1):
    a_list.append(a[i])

while 't' in a_list: a_list.remove('t') # This Removes all lower case "t"s in a_list   

a = ''

# Then you can change it into a string again :
for n in range(0, len(a_list) - 1):
    a += a_list[n]

print(a) # This is the original 'a' only without lower case "t"s
```

But this is **NOT** a good way to do (it's kinda ridicules) i recommend :

.replace(,)

which is already explained

Comment: Explained a lot more above!